# Suma de columnas oracle desde php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo esta consulta desde **PHP**, que no me devuelve valores pero si la ejecuto desde *Oracle SQL Developer* me muestra datos.

```
    $sucursalesaño=[];
    $ventasaño=[];
    $query ='SELECT S.SUCURSAL , SUM(V.TOTAL_VENTAS)
            FROM T_VENTAS V, T_SUCURSAL S, T_TIEMPO T
            WHERE V.ID_TIEMPO= T.ID_TIEMPO AND T.AÑO=2016
            AND S.ID_SUCURSAL =V.ID_SUCURSAL AND V.ID_SUCURSAL IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
            GROUP BY SUCURSAL';
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($stid);
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH)) != false) 
      {
        array_push($sucursalesaño, $row[0]);
        array_push($ventasaño, $row[1]);
      }
    oci_free_statement($stid);
```

Sin en cambio al momento de hacer un consulta desde una sola tabla como la siguiente si me muestra información:

```
SELECT COLONIA,SUM(PRECIOFINAL) PFINAL from TDATOS where LOCATION_CODE=11174 and COLONIA IS NOT NULL GROUP BY COLONIA;
```

La unica diferencia con la función es la consulta, podrían ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Cambiaria OCI_BOTH por OCI_NUM (por optimizar), luego dale un var_export($row) y le pondria el doble igual en el while ( !== false ).
Con el var_export vemos que tiene $row y a partir de ahi tiramos.